# Magento - Remove Category from shopping option block from left side bar

Tags: magento

Before posting this question I have tried my best to find solution for this. I want to remove category layer from the shopping option block on left sidebar of magento.

http://i59.tinypic.com/35mi22u.jpg

I want to remove the marked option from my left sidebar. I need price and color to appear. 
Any help appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

my app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml

```
<dl id="narrow-by-list">
            <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
            <?php $i=0; foreach ($_filters as $_filter): $i++; ?>

            <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
               <dt id="filterlabel<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>

                <script type="text/javascript" >   
                    <?php if($open == 1): ?>     
                        jQuery('#filterlabel<?php echo $i;?>').each(function(){
                            jQuery(this).addClass('active');
                            jQuery(this).toggle(function(){
                                jQuery(this).removeClass('active').next().slideUp(200);
                            },function(){
                                jQuery(this).addClass('active').next().slideDown(200);
                            })
                        });                        
                    <?php elseif($open == 0): ?>     
                        jQuery('#filterlabel<?php echo $i;?>').each(function(){
                            jQuery(this).next().hide();
                            jQuery(this).toggle(function(){
                                jQuery(this).addClass('active').next().slideDown(200);
                            },function(){
                                jQuery(this).removeClass('active').next().slideUp(200);
                            })
                        });    
                    <?php endif; ?>                    
                </script>                   
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying and fiddling with the code I managed to solve my problem.

Goto app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml

Change:

```
<dt id="filterlabel<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
```

to

```
<dt id="filterlabel<?php echo $i;?>"><?php if ($_filter->getName() != 'Category'): {?><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?><?php } endif; ?></dt>
```

Here above I removed just the label 'Category' that is displayed in sidebar.

After that Goto app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml

Change:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>

<li>
    <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?></a>
    <?php else: echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
   <!-- (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)-->
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

to

```
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
<?php if ($this->getName() != 'Category'): {?>
<li>
    <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?></a>
    <?php else: echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
   <!-- (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)-->
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>
<?php } endif; ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Here I removed the list that comes inside the Category layer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to remove the “`Category`” section from my layered navigation
so I wouldnt have any repeat information with the attributes 
I wanted in the layered navigation.

go to `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/layer` and open up `view.phtml` for edit.

```
<dl id="narrow-by-list">
            <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
            <?php $i=0; foreach ($_filters as $_filter): $i++; ?>

            <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                <?php if($_filter->getName() != "Category"){ ?>
                <dt id="filterlabel<?php echo $i;?>">
                    <?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                <?php } endif; ?>

                <script type="text/javascript" >   
                    <?php if($open == 1): ?>     
                        jQuery('#filterlabel<?php echo $i;?>').each(function(){
                            jQuery(this).addClass('active');
                            jQuery(this).toggle(function(){
                                jQuery(this).removeClass('active').next().slideUp(200);
                            },function(){
                                jQuery(this).addClass('active').next().slideDown(200);
                            })
                        });                        
                    <?php elseif($open == 0): ?>     
                        jQuery('#filterlabel<?php echo $i;?>').each(function(){
                            jQuery(this).next().hide();
                            jQuery(this).toggle(function(){
                                jQuery(this).addClass('active').next().slideDown(200);
                            },function(){
                                jQuery(this).removeClass('active').next().slideUp(200);
                            })
                        });    
                    <?php endif; ?>                    
                </script>                   
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
```

Comment: My file looks quite diffrent. I applied the changes according to logic suggested by you. but my whole page goes blank. here is how my file looks like.
I have edit my question to show you how my file looks like.

Comment: Even i changed it the same way. As said the page goes blank.

Answer (score 0):

In your theme catalog.xml file replace

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
```

with

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
<action method="unsetChild"><child>category_filter</child></action>
</block>
```

Comment: This unsets the whole block. I just want to remove category from that block. Check image url.

Comment: No this will not, i have checked. it will only remove the category but not the other attribute filters.Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I did, the whole block disaapeared.